# Jenkins Pipeline throws ProxyException "expected to call Device.<init> but wound up catching Device.getIP"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I create a class in Jenkins pipeline like this.

```
class Device
{
    def ip = null
    def context
    
    def getIP(devName) 
    {
        return "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd"
    }

    Device(context, devName, devType)
    {
        print("[DEBUG] ctor device")
        ip = getIP(devName)
        this.context = context
        print(ip)
    }
}


ap = new Device(this, "DEV", "TYPE")
print ap.ip
```

It works well when I try it in the 'Groovy web console' (https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/)
But when I run this script in Jenkins, the following error occurs.

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline

expected to call Device.<init> but wound up catching Device.getIP; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

hudson.remoting.ProxyException: CpsCallableInvocation{methodName=getIP, call=com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsFunction@20fd33e6, receiver=Device@57905ade, arguments=[DEV]}

Finished: FAILURE
```

What's wrong with the script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Underlying Jenkins pipeline engine transforms your Groovy code to the [groovy-cps](https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps) compatible one. It comes with several limitations, and one of them is calling CPS-transformed method (`getIP` in your case) from the method that is not CPS-transformed (constructor method.)

Here is the [documentation page](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/#constructors) that describes this limitation.

> ### Constructors
>
> Occasionally, users may attempt to use CPS-transformed code such as Pipeline steps inside of a constructor in a Pipeline script. Unfortunately, the construction of objects via the `new` operator in Groovy is not something that can be CPS-transformed ([JENKINS-26313](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26313)), and so this will not work.

You can either remove the call to the `getIP` method from the constructor, or you can annotate `getIP` method with `@NonCPS` annotation.

Comment: @stepniak Hi Another issue occurred, could you check it?

Comment: Read this carefully: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/#use-of-pipeline-steps-fromnoncps and then look at your code.